# Join attempt throwing exceptions

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class, template-toolkit

I'm sure I'm overlooking something glaringly obvious and I apologize for the newbie question, but I've spent several hours back and forth through documentation for DBIx::Class and Catalyst and am not finding the answer I need...

What I'm trying to do is automate creation of sub-menus based on the contents of my database. I have three tables in the database to do so: maps (in which sub-menu items are found), menus (contains names of top-level menus), maps_menus (assigns maps to top-level menus). I've written a subroutine to return a hash of resultsets, with the plan of using a Template Toolkit nested loop to build the top-level and sub-menus.

Basically, for each top-level menu in menus, I'm trying to run the following query and (eventually) build a sub-menu based on the result:

```
select * FROM maps JOIN maps_menus ON maps.id_maps = maps_menus.id_maps WHERE maps_menus.id_menus = (current id_menus);
```

Here is the subroutine, located in lib/MyApp/Schema/ResultSet/Menus.pm

```
# Build a hash of hashes for menu generation
sub build_menu {
    my ($self, $maps, $maps_menus) = @_;

    my %menus;

    while (my $row = $self->next) {
        my $id = $row->get_column('id_menus');
        my $name = $row->get_column('name');
        my $sub = $maps_menus->search(
            { 'id_maps' => $id },
            { join => 'maps',
                '+select' => ['maps.id_maps'],
                '+as' => ['id_maps'],
                '+select' => ['maps.name'],
                '+as' => ['name'],
                '+select' => ['maps.map_file'],
                '+as' => ['map_file']
            }
        );   

        $menus{$name} = $sub;   

        # See if it worked...
        print STDERR "$name\n";
        while (my $m = $sub->next) {
            my $m_id = $m->get_column('id_maps');
            my $m_name = $m->get_column('name');
            my $m_file = $m->get_column('map_file');

            print STDERR "\t$m_id, $m_name, $m_file\n";
        }
    }
    return \%menus;
}
```

I am calling this from lib/MyApp/Controller/Maps.pm thusly...

```
$c->stash(menus => [$c->model('DB::Menus')->build_menu($c->model('DB::Map'), $c->model('DB::MapsMenus'))]);
```

When I attempt to pull up the page, I get all sorts of exceptions, the top-most of which is:

```
[error] No such relationship maps on MapsMenus at /home/catalyst/perl5/lib/perl5/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm line 1078
```

Which, as far as I can tell, originates from the call to $sub->next. I take this as meaning I'm doing my query incorrectly and not getting the results I think I should be. However, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I found the following lines, defining the relationship to maps, in lib/MyApp/Schema/Result/MapsMenus.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "id_map",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::Map",
  { id_maps => "id_maps" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "CASCADE", on_update => "CASCADE" },
);
```

...and in lib/MyApp/Schema/Result/Map.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "maps_menuses",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::MapsMenus",
  { "foreign.id_maps" => "self.id_maps" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
```

No idea why it's calling it "maps_menuses" -- that was generated by Catalyst. Could that be the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you run the query directly what happens?

Comment: I've run the query I quoted in the first block directly in sqlite and I get the results I would expect. The abstraction into DBIx::Class language confuses me, though, and I very well could be doing it wrong there. :-/

Comment: Sounds like it your relationship isn't set up right (as the error message says). I'd look over DBIx documentation again.

Comment: I think you're right, Zach, but I'm still not sure how to fix it. Making some edits to the main post to reflect what I know...

Comment: Make a gist with the perl code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Zach.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Just for Menus.pm, or for everything?

Comment: For everything, need to see how the relationships are set up.

Comment: Alright, it's up at https://gist.github.com/adadiehl/d77dda264d8f883ee698

Comment: This is the part that you need to tweak your relationship in:  `ON maps.id_maps = maps_menus.id_maps` Make sure that exists in MapsMenus and Maps files that you posted.

Comment: I'm still confused. Isn't that what the "__PACKAGE__->has_many( ..." in Map.pm and "__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(..." in MapsMenus.pm are defining?

Comment: Yes but they aren't being mapped right to that ON clause. I added links to the cookbooks to help you out in the gist.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Zach! I managed to sort out the relationship and got the join (mostly) working. Only odd thing now is that it's telling me the column "name" does not exist in my results (it clearly does!) -- everything else prints out just fine, but it doesn't like "name" for some reason...

Comment: Hmmm.. May have spoke to soon. I'm getting results but the query that's being generated from my code is `SELECT me.id_maps, me.id_menus, maps.map_file FROM maps_menus me  JOIN maps maps ON maps.id_maps = me.id_maps WHERE ( id_menus = ? ): '4'`  Now I'm really confused, because it IS getting map_file right, just none of the others. Made updates to my code at gist if you have time to take a look...

Comment: Okay, found the problem. I had the direction of the join reversed in the relationship. Putting the "has_many" in maps_menus and the "belongs_to" in maps and doing the join on maps instead of maps_menus got it working. So simple!

Comment: glad to see you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using prefetch of the two relationships which form the many-to-many relationship helper and maybe using HashRefInflator if you don't need access to the row objects.

Note that Catalyst doesn't generate a DBIC (which is btw the official abbreviation for DBIx::Class, DBIx is a whole namespace) schema, SQL::Translator or DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader do. Looks at the docs of the module you've used to find out how to influence its naming.
Also feel free to change the names if they don't fit you.